# openActiveSession fails on iOS 5.1 with 3.5.1 SDK

Tags: ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions in my app written with the 3.5.1 SDK.. 
The code works great most of the time, but on device with iOS 5.1, it does not work.. 
I already tried resetting the device;  I don't think it is device configuration, but the same code works fine on iOS 6.1 (devices and simulator; code even works in iOS 5.1 simulator.. but no dice on iOS 5.1 devive..

Any idea what is going on? I used charles to peek at traffic and I see two very different call paths between device (error) and simulator (works)...   The device one always fails with a trace that looks like this..

The app is not sandboxed. [though i do get same error in sandbox app]

thanks!!

---- Charles trace --

{
    "error_code": 1,
    "error_msg": "An unknown error occurred",
    "request_args": [{
        "key": "method",
        "value": "auth.iosauthorizeapp"
    }, {
        "key": "proxied_app_id",
        "value": "SKIPPEDBUTLOOKSVALID"
    }, {
        "key": "ios_bundle_id",
        "value": "com.thepickking"
    }, {
        "key": "sdk_version",
        "value": "3"
    }, {
        "key": "format",
        "value": "json"
    }, {
        "key": "app_version",
        "value": "202949"
    }, {
        "key": "proxied_app_name",
        "value": "The Pick King"
    }, {
        "key": "permissions",
        "value": "basic_info"
    }, {
        "key": "locale",
        "value": "en_US"
    }, {
        "key": "sdk",
        "value": "ios"
    }, {
        "key": "access_token",
        "value": "SKIPPEDBUTLOOKSVALID"
    }]
}

--- My code looks like this: -----

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot.. or what could be going wrong? ?

Thanks!!

Comment: On your iOS 5.1 device, what login dialog do you see - the one shown in the Facebook app, mobile Safari, something else? If the Facebook app is installed, which version is it?

Comment: Hi, Facebook app is installed. Version (in settings) says it is 202949.  
Here are two screenshots of login: http://twitpic.com/cva7uq and http://twitpic.com/cva8gy...    

Thanks!

Comment: The difference between 5.1 simulator (which works for you) and 5.1 device (which doesn't appear to), is on the device you're authenticating against the Facebook app. It's not clear why that's failing. Can you get the other FB samples to fail on 5.1 device? Try SessionLoginSample and Scrumptious.

Comment: Hi C,  
SessionLogin works on the phone but uses a different API (-Session openWithCompletionhandler.
What is the most reliable API for login/auth?? There is two samples and they use different APIs. 
Here are findings on the difference btw simulator and phone: 
If I uninstall the facebook app, my app works fine on phone.
I tried debugging into facebook's source and put stack traces with frame variables for each scenario [here](http://sdrv.ms/ZuySd2)   
Results: 
device w/ facebook app: Unknown error.
Device w/o facebook app: OK  
Simulator (no app): OK 
What else should I look at? 
THanks!

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you temporarily change the code in the SessionLoginSample, in the buttonClickHandler: method, in the else clause: delete what's currently there and add the following and see if it works? [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,                FBSessionState status,
NSError *error) {
     appDelegate.session = FBSession.activeSession;
     [self updateView];
}];

Comment: Hi C, 
Great suggestions.. lots of new data: 
If I change the code in SessionLoginSample, it worked.. 
I then changed my PLIST to your settings.. DisplayName, URLType, bundleId, and FaceboookAppId..  My code works with your settings. 
I then put my settings in SessionLoginSample..  and it did not work..
My settings have a space in DisplayName. it is "The Pick King" (no quotes of course..  Could that be a problem?  Else my app is misconfigured elsewhere.. I can't change the DisplayName for my app since it is production. Should I escape it?

Comment: Just double checking, it should be FacebookDisplayName that you're setting in your app. You can cut and paste the value from the App Dashboard. The space should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi C, yes, I meant FacebookDisplayName.. 
If the space is not the issue, any suggestions on what to look at?

Comment: Space is not the issue. But I can reproduce your issue (against your app). One other thing to test is to create a new test app with the same Display Name and you can try same bundle ID. Only difference should be the namespace. Then put the new app info in your test app. Assumption is only the app ID (for the new app) will be different. My guess is that may not fail. If so, you can start comparing your existing and new app settings and try to to get the new app to fail. I'm thinking there may be something different about your settings that may require you to file a bug to better sort this out.